# How to transfer new data to array using swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a tableView(purchases cart), which include magazines in multiple sections. In section, we can see cells with stuff from magazine. In the cell, I did display UILabel(price), UILabel(count) and UILabel with summary price (item * count) in one cell. Also, we can see two buttons (plus and minus), for changing count of item. Example -

```
var count: Float =  Float(cell.countLabel.text!)!
guard Int(count) > 1 else { return }
var shortPrice = cell.newPrice.text
shortPrice?.removeLast(2)
let floatPrice = Float(shortPrice!)
count -= 1
let newSumShortPrice = floatPrice! * count
cell.countLabel.text = String(Int(count))
cell.summPrice.text = "\(newSumShortPrice) ₽"
```

But changes didn't work with an array.

The strcuct of my model -

```
struct ViewModel {
    var name: String?
    var offers: [Offers]?
}


   struct Offers : Mappable {
        var count : Int?
        var fullPrice : String?
        var shortPrice : String?
    }
var purchasesViewModel = [PurchaseList.Fetch.ViewModel]()
```

I know, that I must pass changed data (count) to my array and use method `tableView.reloadData()`. But I can't, because I don't know how to do that.

How I can transfer new `count` value (check struct Offers) to array `purchasesViewModel`?

Comment: can you show your cellForRowAt method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the index of the array and delete the particular data(old data) from purchasesViewModel and recreate new data and insert it on that index. I hope this will work.